# How do I cluster values of y axis against x axis in scatterplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Lets say I've 2 arrays
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
y = [1,2,2,2,3,4,5]

its scatter plot looks like this

[image]

what I want to do is that I want my x axis to look like this in the plot

0,4,8

as a result of which values of y in each piece of x should come closer .
The similar behavior I've seen is bar plots where this is called clustering , how do I do the same in case of scatter plot , or is there any other plot I should be using ?

I hope my question is clear/understandable .
All the help is appreciated

Comment: How do you decide which original x-value goes to which cluster? E.g. to which cluster should `x=6` go?

Comment: Could you modify the figure 'by hand' to show what result you are expecting ? Or link to an example somewhere

Answer (score 0):

With you plot, try this, before you display the plot.

```
plt.xticks([0,4,8]))
```

or

```
import numpy as np
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 8+1, step=4))
```

Then to change the scale you can try something like this,

```
plt.xticks([0,4,8]))
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (10,5)
```

I got this with my example,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 30)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.xticks([0,4,8])
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (7,3)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', color='black')
```

output

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, OP not only wants to change the ticks, but also *"values of y in each piece of x should come closer"*

Comment: @JohanC exactly

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is close to [swarmplots](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html) and [stripplots](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html) in Seaborn. However, Seaborn's swarmplot and stripplot are purely categorical on one of the axes, which means that they wouldn't preserve the relative x-axis order of your elements inside each category.
One way to do what you want would be to increase the space in your x-axis between categories ([0,4,8]) and modify your `xticks` accordingly.
Below is an example of this where I assign the data to 3 different categories: [-2,2[, [2,6[, [6,10[. And each bar is `dil_k` away from its directly neighboring bars.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Generating data
x= np.random.choice(8,size=(100))
y= np.random.choice(8,size=(100))
dil_k=20

#Creating the spacing between categories
x[np.logical_and(x<6, x>=2)]+=dil_k
x[np.logical_and(x<10, x>=6)]+=2*dil_k

#Plotting
ax=plt.scatter(x,y)

#Modifying axes accordingly
plt.xticks([0,2,22,24,26,46,48,50],[0,2,2,4,6,6,8,10])

plt.show()
```

And the output gives:

[image]

Alternatively, if you don't care about keeping the order of your elements along the x-axis inside each category, then you can use swarmplot directly.
The code can be seen below:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

#Generating data
x= np.random.choice(8,size=(100))
y= np.random.choice(8,size=(100))


#Creating the spacing between categories
x[np.logical_and(x<2,x>=-2)]=0
x[np.logical_and(x<6, x>=2)]=4
x[np.logical_and(x<10, x>=6)]=8

#Plotting
sns.swarmplot(x=x,y=y)


plt.show()
```

And the output gives:

[image]